# In Playwright (Python) when there are multiple buttons on a page, all with the same name, how do i select correct button?

Tags: python, playwright

If I am implementing string locators, such as:

```
continue_button: str = "button:has-text(\"Continue\")"
```

If there are multiple buttons on the same page that say continue, but are for different paths, how do I select the correct continue... is there a way to add an index to that string locator?

Comment: That's just a CSS selector. so you can add appropriate parent elements to the selector to uniquely identify it. Without knowing the web page we can't answer specifically, but e.g. something like `#header div button:has-text("Continue")`, etc.

Comment: Please share a [mcve], the page and the elements you want. Without that information, it's impossible to help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is several good practices for creating locators/selectors.
Using playwright there is official documentation for each common and unique selector on how-to and what-is doing.

More information in https://playwright.dev/docs/selectors#text-selector

About your case, i would suggest always to use an parent selector for locating an element.
When there is a button, try to find its unique parent.

- By id
- By unique class
- Something else unique.

Example:

```
<dv id=test>
 <button id=continue-test>Continue</button>
</div>
```

In this case you can use the unique id of the button and not the text.
Selector css: `#continue-test`
But if you, don't have an unique identifier for the button you can use the parent and go down to the button.
Selector css: `#test > button`

Matching text using css is not possible, but with XPATH can look like this:

```
//button[text()="Continue"]
```

This selector **MATCHES** the text using *"equals"*.

Using playwright:

```
button:has-text("Continue")
```

Using has-text and quotes - matches the text using equals.
If you are using another selector for example `text=Continue`, this will match all elements that **CONTAINS** the text *"Continue"*

All this is explained with example in the official documentation for playwright selectors.
That does not mean to not use *XPATH* to achieve the goals.

**CSS** selectors are *fast* but kind of restricted to work with text.

**Xpath** is *quite slower* but much more powerful to work in text/parent/child elements etc.

I would suggest **always** to use an parent element with unique identifier and go down to reach your actual element, which will receive the interaction.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that I love Playwright is because of scenarios like this and how easily it can be handled.

If you have a string named `abc` and there are multiple occurrences of that string on a single page, then you can use the `nth-match` criteria to pick the `nth` element.

For eg ,

```
await page.locator(':nth-match(:text("abc"), 3)').click();
```

will select the `3rd` occurrence of the word `abc`. Similarly, in your case, if you want to select the first or second or third, you can simply do

```
 await page.locator(':nth-match(:text("Continue"), 1)').click();
 
 await page.locator(':nth-match(:text("Continue"), 2)').click();
 
 await page.locator(':nth-match(:text("Continue"), 3)').click();
```

Please refer to the Selectors documentation for Playwright -> [Selectors](https://playwright.dev/docs/selectors#pick-n-th-match-from-the-query-result)

This is different than the `nth-child` concept as mentioned

> Unlike :nth-child(), elements do not have to be siblings, they could
> be anywhere on the page. In the snippet above, all three buttons match
> :text("Buy") selector, and :nth-match() selects the third button.